# Uniquiness of field with extra validation

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I am new to Symfony2 and stuck at validation part.

In my project any user can add there Product in database and any user can have same Product name which is already existing for other user.

Here we can not use Unique validation for product name because that will violate my requirement. So can anyone help me to resolve the problem?

Thanks!
Avmishra

Comment: Why don't you simply use an auto-incremental id? I suppose that name is primary key of your entity ...

Comment: You can set multiple fields for the `UniqueEntity` constraint so you should be able to set `[name, user]` and it should then check for the existence of those 2 fields combined rather than just the name or user - http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html

Comment: @Qoop very helpful. please give this as ans so that I can accept it. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set multiple fields for the [UniqueEntity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) constraint so you should be able to set `[name, user]` and it should then check for the existence of those 2 fields combined rather than just the name or user.